# What does "to be a range of time shy of a date" mean?

Tags: phrases

Consider the following paragraph ([Huffington Post](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/07/26/ronald-post-obese-ohio-in_n_3659348.html)):

> Ronald Post died Thursday morning at a prison hospital where he'd been treated on and off since 2011, a state prisons spokeswoman said. He was a week shy of his 54th birthday.

What does the last sentence mean? What are its particular connotations?

Comment: Questions that can be answered easily by looking at general references are considered off topic here. You can find the answer to this question by looking up [‘shy’](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shy?q=shy) in any dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

It simply means the death occured one week before he was to turn 54. See [Def. #6 in Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shy), which also mentions that that usage of the word is chiefly North American.

The term isn't only be used for ages and time; it could be used for other numerical amounts, too. For example:

> I wanted to buy two tickets, but I was three dollars shy [of having enough money to purchase a second ticket].
>
> I need to start dieting soon. My current weight is 4 pounds shy of my all-time high.
>
> The heat wave continues in the west, with temperatures just a few degrees shy of breaking records.

Comment: Per the OED, it was originally betting slang, first surfacing in the late 1800s in the United States. The first citation given there is **“1895** *Funk’s Stand. Dict.* s.v., — Having a less amount of money at stake than is called for by the rules of the game; short; as, ***to be shy a dollar*** in the pool.” A more recent provided citation is: **“1975** R. Stout *Family Affair* (1976) iv. 46 — I merely thought some women were ***a little shy on brains***, present company not excepted.”

Comment: Notwithstanding that the definition from Collins mentions this usage as mainly N.Am., I disagree. I wouldn't have said that such usage is unusual in the UK, and [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shy?q=shy) doesn't make that distinction.