# Using shy or short to indicate shortage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, vocabulary

I am hoping to gain a better understanding of how the words "shy" and "short" are used to indicate a shortage.

1. The order will be shy/short of 10 cases.
2. The order will be 10 cases shy/short.
3. We shorted the customer 10 cases.
4. We shorted the customer by 10 cases.

If someone could help critique the sentences above, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "to be a range of time shy of a date" mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120635/what-does-to-be-a-range-of-time-shy-of-a-date-mean)

Comment: You can't say 'we shorted the customer' (not in my English, at any rate). _The delivery to the customer was ten cases short._

Comment: I'd say all but the first one are idiomatic in informal US English.  ("Of" is not appropriate in the first example.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order will be shy/short of 10 cases
Either one works but you'll need to add "just" in front of both..IF you're going to keep "of"
Otherwise, ..be shy/short 10 cases.

The order will be 10 cases shy/short
Short. Never shy

We shorted the customer 10 cases
Correct

We shorted the customer by 10 cases.
Correct

Comment: Appreciate your response! We use this quite often at work and I'm always afraid that I'm not using the terms correctly.

Comment: Saying "shy/short **of**" is ambiguous.  Unclear whether the quantity is less than 10, or it is 10 less than the necessary quantity.